# Elasticsearch create a mapping for nested array

Tags: python, arrays, json, elasticsearch, schema

i have  to create indexing using elasticsearch and python for the json data which need to be indexed example i have an nested array array [[39.909971141540645, 1452077285.150548, 1452077286.196072, 1.0455241203308105]] i need to define an mapping for this array like first field is count , second field is start_time, end_time, duration . please help how to declare mapping for nested array.

i have declared mapping using python  and elasticsearch module

```
index_mapping={
 "properties": {
"speed_events":{
"type":"object",
"properties":{
"count":{"type":"double"},
"start_time":{"type":"date"},
 "end_time":{"type":"date"},
"duration":{"type":"double"}
}}}
es.indices.put_mapping(index=index_name, doc_type=type_name,      body=index_mapping)
```

its throwing error object mapping for [speed_events] tried to parse field [null] as object, but found a concrete value')
need help to fix this

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [nested mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-mapping.html) for this.
This will ensure each of the nested objects are treated independently from other. See [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html)

Anyway I don't think it's possible to index anonymous two level nested arrays.
You need to name the properties in the nested level.

So assumming order of properties as in mapping `count, start_time, end_time, duration` this will not work:

```
[  
   [  
      1,
      '1999-01-01',
      '2000-01-01',
      14.6
   ],
   [  
      2,
      '1999-01-01',
      '2000-01-01',
      16.6
   ]
]
```

but you should instead produce something like this:

```
[  
   {  
      'count':1,
      'start_time':'1999-01-01',
      'end_time':'2000-01-01',
      'duration':14.6
   },
   {  
      'count':2,
      'start_time':'1999-01-01',
      'end_time':'2000-01-01',
      'duration':16.6
   }
]
```